# Append multiple arguments and use them in a single command

Tags: bash, loops, wine

So what I'm intending to do here is to create a part of a script that can open a single or multiple torrents with µtorrent (through wine).

The Wine path needs to be appended to the arguments like so (the loop is obviously not working):

```
for i in "$@"; do
  open="Z:/$(pwd)/$i"
done

wine utorrent "$open"
```

Comment: Can you give an example to see what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @fedorqui, well, I mean just like I stated that when typing something like "that_script lol.torrent another_one.torrent" it'd open them up. Whatever files the user types to be opened need to be passed to that single line so that they're opened all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an array:

```
args=()
pwd=$(pwd)
for i; do
    args+=("z:/$pwd/$i")
done
wine utorrent "${args[@]}"
```

In a bash `for` loop, if you leave out the `in ...` clause, it  iterates over `"$@"` by default.

Comment: Oh yeah. Hadn't thought of that. Beautiful to have a place like this where you can just come to for an answer and sooner than you know you gonna have one.

Comment: Btw. I'm assuming there's something wrong with just: `for i; do args+=("z:/$(pwd)/$i"); done` then? (Followed by the wine line.)

Comment: Thanks. -Filler for the char limit-